# Need to update a window when another window is closed. Need to instantiate the closed window again

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to update my `MainWindow` by closing another window called `newProjectWindow`. I have an `Eventhandler` that updates my `Mainwindow` when the `newProjectWindow` is closed but I need the `newProjectWindow` again. But if I try to `NewProjectWindow.ShowDialog();` I get an error.

Is there a possibility where I can somehow "reuse" the Window.

Comment: but how am I gonna check for the ClosedEvent?

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is under 50 so I can not wirte a comment and I need to say it here :

Try to hide your NewProjectWindow instead of closing it .

Or you can make a new instance of your NewProjectWindow and show the new one.

Comment: But I need it the closedevent